# SOAP Ruby On Rails logon Affili.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I try to logon Affili.net via SOAP by using the savon-gem.

```
  client = Savon.client do
    wsdl "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl"
  end

  message =       {
    'Username' => '123123',
    'Password' => '123123',
    'ins2:WebServiceType' => 'Publisher' }

  response = client.call(:logon, :message => message)
```

But I only get this exception:

```
(a:DeserializationFailed) The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc:LogonRequestMsg. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 777. 'EndElement' 'LogonRequestMsg' from namespace 'http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc' is not expected. Expecting element 'Username | Password | WebServiceType'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

https://developer-api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl

Whats wrong?

**Update**

Now i tried some tools like this:

http://www.soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper-api.affili.net%2FV2.0%2FLogon.svc%3Fwsdl&_ArraySize=2

And it also tells me: it does not work. But my Account and that credentials are ok!

So I tried it on PHP

```
define ("WSDL_LOGON", "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl");
define ("WSDL_STATS",  "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/PublisherStatistics.svc?wsdl");

$Username   = '123123'; // the publisher ID
$Password   = '123123'; // the publisher web services password

$SOAP_LOGON = new SoapClient(WSDL_LOGON);
$Token      = $SOAP_LOGON->Logon(array(
             'Username'  => $Username,
             'Password'  => $Password,
             'WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'
             ));
echo $Token;
```

and it works!

Whats the difference between all online tools, all offline tools and Ruby on Rails and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `message` with symbolized keys, like this:

```
  message = {
    logon: {
      username: '123123',
      password: '123123',
      web_service_type: 'Publisher' 
    }
  }
```

Comment: that does not change anything

Comment: @Paket2001 what if add namespace `logon` or `logon_request` (updated my answer)

Comment: it was a good idea to try it symbolized but it does not work. And the WSDL tells me it is ok to have the msg like i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know the difference between the savon (2.7.2) and the PHP implementation.

But there is a solution for affili.net by using **savon 3** (but it is not stable yet!)

```
client = Savon.new("https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl")

logon_body = {
  LogonRequestMsg: {
    'Username' => '123123',
    'Password' => '123123',
    'WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'
  }
}

operation = client.operation('Authentication', 'DefaultEndpointLogon', 'Logon')
operation.body = logon_body
response = operation.call

puts response.body[:credential_token]
```

Some Savon 3 Documentation: http://savonrb.com/version3/getting-started.html

And the github branch: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/tree/version3